# Why Gradle release plugins generally don't modify version in build.gradle?

Tags: gradle

I was wondering why Gradle release plugins generally do not modify version in `build.gradle`?

In Maven it made sense that version was directly modified in `pom.xml`. In Gradle plugin generally just add a tag but the version in `build.gradle` is not tracked.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out.

In Maven things are easy - version is statically defined in pom.xml in vell defined place. Period.

In Gradle, things are more complicated as version can be arbitrary object (does not have to be String or number) and there might be dynamic logic to determine the version, e.g. from the VCS.

So **Gradle release plugins cannot generally modify version**.